# Получить аттрибуты TreeNode

Tags: c#, xml, asp.net, treeview

Есть у меня 
`<siteMapNode title="title" url="http://example.com/example.aspx" description="description"/>` 
такого рода xml файлик.
Я подгружаю его в `TreeView1`.
И есть по клику на елемент ивент `TreeView1_SelectedNodeChanged`.

Суть вопроса:
Как получить аттрибуты `title`, `url`, `description` у заданой `SelectedNode` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

У TreeView узлы, привязанные к данным sitemap находятся в режиме *навигации*, т.е. при щелчке на узел будет происходить переход на новую страницу, поэтому событие OnSelectedNodeChanged не сработает.

По умолчнаию узлы работают в режиме *выбора*, но если свойству NavigateUrl присвоить значение, отличное от пустой строки, то узел перейдет в режим *навигации*. Это как раз и происходит при связывании с данными sitemap'а.

Значения атрибутов siteMapNode отображаются на свойства TreeNode следующим образом:

- `title -> Value, Text`
- `description -> ToolTip`
- `url -> NavigateUrl`

**Дополнение:** А еще режим работы узлов можно переключать между *Ничего*/*Выбор*/*Разворачивать-Сворачивать*/*Выбор и разворачивать-сворачивать*. Может кому полезно будет. Так что можно выставить режим взаимодействия *Ничего* и работать не с событием **Выбор Узла** а событием **OnMouse**.

*Дополнение №2:* А еще вот [тут](http://terroare.blogspot.com/2013/02/datatable-to-treeview-in-c-displaying.html) парни рассказывают, как с помощью DataTable реализовать возможность работы с аттрибутами через отдельную ноду, как в Windows Forms.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ, сам минут 30 назад додумался.